# In asp is it possible to have one or more function within a funciton?

Tags: vb6, asp-classic

I was wondering if its possible to have one or more functions within a funciton like in jQuery?   I need to add an inline function that performs a simple task but I really don't need it anywhere except the function I'm calling it from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible, but you could create a class with the functions you need.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I may need to use a class b/c I need to limit the resources being used.  thx